# Python: Getting "TypeError" during checking whether a json key exist or not?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Below there is a small part of json file which is I am processing.

```
  {
      'kind': 'c',
      'items': [
        {
          'kind': 'c',
          'title': 'D',
          'htmlTitle': 'P',
          'link': 'h',
          'pagemap': {
            'hcard': [
              {
                'fn': 'A',
                'title': 'S'
              }
            ],
            'person': [
              {
                'org': 't',

              }
            ],
            'cse_image': [
              {
                'src': 'h'
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

As some items have person key in it while some don't have. So for checking whether items contains person key or not, I am using below code:

```
json = json.dumps(results)
for profile in range (0, 10):
    if 'person' not in json['items'][profile]['pagemap']:
        org="null"
    else:
        org= results['items'][profile]['pagemap']['person'][0]['org']
        #results stores the json response.
```

But on running the program it gives an error stating "TypeError: string indices must be integers".

Comment: Why are you calling `json.dumps`?

Comment: Your `json` variable is a string... what do you expect `json['items']` to do???

Comment: When I'm using reesults instead of json 
if 'person' not in results['items'][profile]['pagemap']:
I am getting the KeyError
org = results['items'][profile]['pagemap']['person'][0]['org']
KeyError: 'org'

Comment: you went as far as `org`. That's good. Now print `results['items'][profile]['pagemap']['person'][0]` you'll know the issue

Comment: On using json.loads getting error:
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict'

Comment: results['items'][profile]['pagemap']['person'][0]
Producing error, KeyError: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing variable names like json and results which is confusing. So I have renamed as needed to achieve what you may actually want.

The json file is "test.json" in this example as I do not know your json filename.

I left the print lines in so you can see what is happening. You may remove them when tested.

```
with open('test.json') as r:
    dic = json.load(r)

result = []

for profile in range(len(dic['items'])):
    print('profile:', profile)
    print('pagemap:', dic['items'][profile]['pagemap'])

    if 'person' not in dic['items'][profile]['pagemap']:
        org = "null"
    else:
        org = dic['items'][profile]['pagemap']['person'][0]['org']

    print('org:', org)
    result += [org]

print('result:', result)
```